# How do I determine which changes in one branch are missing from another?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, dvcs

I'm using git.  I have a branch, `apifixes`, that was branched from `master` some time ago.  Most, but not all, of the changes from the `apifixes` branch have been merged back into `master`.  At least, I believe this is the case, because when I try to do

```
git branch -d apifixes
```

I get the following error:

```
error: The branch 'apifixes' is not an ancestor of your current HEAD.
```

How can I tell which changes are in `apifixes` but not in `master`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git log master..apifixes
```

show commits reachable from apifixes, but not from master

if you want to show the difference between the two, use `git diff` instead

Comment: I might have misunderstood your answer, but `git log master..apifixes` does not show me changes that are *only* in `apifixes` and *not* in `master`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: yes, `master..apifixes` will only show you changes in `apifixes` and not in `master`. am **i** missing something? i thought that was your question »How can I tell which changes are in apifixes but not in master?«

Comment: if you cherry-picked single commits from apifixes and applied them to master, this will also show the cherry-picked commits in the log. git compares ancestry information and not actual commit contents.

Comment: Now that I'm back at work, I can try again.  I think this must be what has happened.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`git log --oneline --left-right --cherry-pick master...apifixes` (note the three dots `...`) might be what you want.